# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in reactJS when uploading image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to let users to upload images but when I try to call uploadhandler, i get error.
If I call this.props.uploadDocumentRequest outside of handleFileUpload, there no problem. But when I call it inside of the handler I get the error.
I'm using React and Redux.

This is the code:

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class File extends Component {
  handleFileUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file, file.name);
    this.props.uploadDocumentRequest({
      file,
      name: file.name
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileUpload} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(File);
```

This is the error i get:

Appreciate your help in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQUSY.png)

Comment: `<input type="file" onChange={() => this.handleFileUpload()} />`

Comment: Could you console.log `this` as well, and update the question with the output? It's strange that `this` would be undefined

Answer (score 1):

Either `bind()` your function or use an arrow function.

a) Inside your constructor (when you add one)

```
this.handleFileUpload = this.handleFileUpload.bind(this)
```

b) Use an arrow function, change your function to

```
handleFileUpload = () => {
  // your function body
}
```